# Ubuntu: how to remove emacs 23 data files

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, uninstall, apt-get

I had emacs 23 installed via `apt-get`, but I want to remove it completely before upgrading to emacs 24.

I did

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs*
```

to remove emacs 23.

But some emacs 23 files remain. `locate emacs` shows:

```
/etc/emacs
...
/usr/lib/emacsen-common
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages
...
/usr/lib/emacsen-common
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/compat
...
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake-mode.el
...
```

I was wondering if it is safe to remove all these? And what's the proper way to remove these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dpkg-query -S /some/file...` to find which package owns the file,
then remove that package, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are not specific to Emacs-23, so they'll be reinstalled when you install `emacs24`.  Furthermore, you can have both `emacs23` and `emacs24` installed at the same time, without any conflict.  I actually have `emacs20`, `emacs21`, `emacs22`, `emacs23`, and `emacs24` all installed here at the same time.